# How is the causes and solutions -[__NSCFConstantString trim]?

Tags: objective-c

I use the `j2objc` .
from java to `objective-c` (ios)

```
2013-06-01 16:17:10.770 tttttt[4433:907] -[__NSCFConstantString trim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2aba60
2013-06-01 16:17:10.774 tttttt[4433:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString trim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2aba60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x311d93e7 0x38ed4963 0x311dcf31 0x311db64d 0x31133208 0x114d2d 0x124625 0x151329 0x150905 0x150e3b 0x1505e3 0xfbe53 0x330d3087 0x330d303b 0x330d3015 0x330d28cb 0x330d2db9 0x32ffb5f9 0x32fe88e1 0x32fe81ef 0x34d005f7 0x34d00227 0x311ae3e7 0x311ae38b 0x311ad20f 0x3112023d 0x311200c9 0x34cff33b 0x3303c2b9 0xfb71f 0x39301b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

please tell me the causes and solutions

Comment: I'll tell you the "causes and solutions" once I get more "context and code"

Comment: You are calling a method that doesn't actually exist or is recognized by the compiler. Check if "NSString trim" exist in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is the lack of the method `[NSString trim]`.  See the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 1):

You want to trim a NSSString and that isnt possible. There isnt even a trim method. Strings are immutable objects anyways.

so you want to EITHER make a new string

```
NSString *b = [a stringByTrimming...];
```

OR you make a mutable copy and trim that

```
NSMutableString *b = [a mutableCopy];
[b trim...];
....
[b release]; //if you don't use ARC, you need to release b
```